# Image Comparison not working with Camera captured images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]I am working on comparing two images for differences.
Problem is that it works fine when I download some image from web, but not work when I tried to compare images which are captured from Phone camera.  Any idea where an I doing it wrong?

I m working in Google Colab. I tried using 'structural_similarity' and `dilate` and `findContours` method, both are not working with camera images.

I tried using template matching then align the image and then try to capture the differences but still got the same result.

As you see in picture - it shows all the nits n bits of differences but not showing the bigger object as a difference.

Phone captured image1:
[image]

Phone captured image2:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import imutils

ref = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Image Comparison/1.png')
target = cv2.imread('/content/drive/My Drive/Image Comparison/2.png')
gray_ref = cv2.cvtColor(ref, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_compare = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(score, diff) = structural_similarity(gray_ref,gray_compare, full=True)
diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

no_of_differences = 0

for c in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    rect_area = w*h
    
    if rect_area > 10:
        no_of_differences +=1
        cv2.rectangle(ref, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(target, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

print("# of differences = ", no_of_differences)
scale_percent = 60 # percent of original size
width = int(ref.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(target.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized_ref = cv2.resize(ref, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized_target = cv2.resize(target, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2_imshow(resized_ref)
cv2_imshow(resized_target)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please show us your work to reproduce your issue.  Please see [mcve] and [ask].  In addition, "not working" is not enough for us to diagnose your problem.  Please be more specific in the errors you are facing.

Comment: don't just dump the code in the question. at least make sure it's styled properly.

Comment: apologize for the inconvenience - will be careful next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues with your solution:

- `structural_similarity` returns positive and negative values (in range [-1, 1]).
  The conversion: `diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")` applies range [0, 1], but for range [-1, 1], we may use the following conversion:

  ```
   diff = ((diff+1) * 127.5).astype("uint8")  # Convert from range [-1, 1] to [0, 255].
  ```
- Using `cv2.threshold` with automatic threshold `cv2.THRESH_OTSU` is not good enough for thresholding the image (at least not when applies after `structural_similarity`).
  We may replace it with [adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga72b913f352e4a1b1b397736707afcde3) - adaptive gaussian threshold instead.
  (My suggested solution is still not optimal, because I had to tune the arguments manually, but finding a general solution seems too difficult).
  Replace `thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]` with:

  ```
   thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(diff, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 175, 30)  # Use adaptive gaussian threshold instead of cv2.THRESH_OTSU
  ```

---

Code sample (without using Google Colb):

```
import cv2
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity
import imutils

ref = cv2.imread('1.png')
target = cv2.imread('2.png')

ref = ref[(ref.shape[0]-480):(ref.shape[0]+480), (ref.shape[1]-768):(ref.shape[1]+768), :]
target = target[(target.shape[0]-480):(target.shape[0]+480), (target.shape[1]-768):(target.shape[1]+768), :]

gray_ref = cv2.cvtColor(ref, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_compare = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

(score, diff) = structural_similarity(gray_ref, gray_compare, full=True)

#diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
diff = ((diff+1) * 127.5).astype("uint8")  # Support negative values (range of diff is [-1, 1])

#thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(diff, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 175, 30)  # Use adaptive gaussian threshold instead of cv2.THRESH_OTSU

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

no_of_differences = 0

for c in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    rect_area = w*h

    if rect_area > 10:
        no_of_differences +=1
        cv2.rectangle(ref, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(target, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

print("# of differences = ", no_of_differences)
scale_percent = 60 # percent of original size
width = int(ref.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(target.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized_ref = cv2.resize(ref, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
resized_target = cv2.resize(target, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow('diff', diff)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('resized_ref', resized_ref)
cv2.imshow('resized_target', resized_target)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Original `diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")`:
[image]
As you can see, there are data overflows.

`diff = ((diff+1) * 127.5).astype("uint8")`:
[image]

Original `thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]`:
[image]
As you can see, about half of `thresh` is white.

Result of `thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(diff, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 175, 30)`:
[image]

---

`resized_target`:
[image]

`resized_ref`:
[image]

Remark:
The images you have posted include the markings, and are not the same size.
Next time, try to post clean images instead of screenshots...

Comment: Thanks a lot - its working - appreciate your help - Can you please help in one more thing - What if I don't wanna mark the tiny differences and only want to show the bigger ones. As there are so many red marks - I don't even understand what the actual difference is. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, replace `if rect_area > 10` with `if rect_area > 1000` (for example). You may also filter by `cv2.contourArea(c)` or check `if (w > 30) And (h > 30)` ...

Comment: Thanks for ur help but its still not working with the actual pictures of the project. I m so confused as its working with other snaps but not with the project photos.  Uploading the actual image where it is not detecting the guage. Can u please help again with that.

Comment: There are no magics... In the case of the pipes, it is not working because the two images are captured from slightly different position and angles - the two images are not perfectly aligned. You may try image alignment techniques before the similarity check (like placing the image one on top of the other). In case of the pipes sample, image alignment it's not going to work so well because there are 3D issues. My answer came with a warning: "finding a general solution seems too difficult". Sorry...